# Query specificly indexed value in multivalued field

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I have a multivalued field which is filled by an array of strings. Now I want to find all documents that have i. e. `foo` as the i. e. second (!) string in this field. Is this possible?

If it is not, what would be your recommendation to achieve this?

Comment: is it solr or elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Solr, you can use UpdateRequestProcessor to copy and modify the field to add position prefix. So, you'll end up with 2_91 or similar. You can use [StatelessScriptURP](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html) for that.

Alternatively, you could send this information as multiple fields and have dynamic field definition to map them.

Basically, for both Solr and ES, underlying Lucene stores multivalued strings as just one long string with large token offset between last token of first value and first token of second value. So, absolute positions require some sort of hack. Runtime hacks (e.g. ElasticSearch example in the other answer) are expensive during query. Content modifying hacks (e.g. URP in this example) are expensive with additional disk space or with more complex schema.

Comment: What I finaly did, was mapping the array client side with a position prefix as you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch, you can achieve this using [Script Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html), Here is a sample,

consider a mapping for phone_no as,

```
{
   "index": {
      "mappings": {
         "type": {
            "properties": {
               "phone_no": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

put a document (first),

```
POST index/type
{
    "phone_no" :["91","92210"]
}
```

and second one too,

```
POST index/type
{
    "phone_no" :["92210","91"]
}
```

so, if you want to find the second value equals 91, then here is a query,

```
POST index/type/_search
{
    "filter" :{
        "script": {
           "script": "_source.phone_no[1].equals(val)",
           "params": {
               "val" :"91"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

where , val can be user defined,

Here in the above script, no case is handled (like, if it have size >1 , which may return execption sometime, you can modify script for your need ). Thanks,

Hope this might helps!!

Comment: This got to be pretty slow? It's bypassing all the actual reasons Lucene actually makes search fast, uses script, AND requires parsing the source field.

Comment: Accessing _source is much slower compared to using _doc but the data is not loaded into memory. For a single field access _fields may be faster than using _source due to the extra overhead of potentially parsing large documents. However, _source may be faster if you access multiple fields or if the source has already been loaded for other purposes.(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_source_field) 
And, you cannot do this using other options, so loading phone_no by using source filtering can improve performance.